# Changing Theme while keeping color/fonts in VS2013

Tags: fonts, colors, themes

I am reasonably new to Visual Studio, so forgive me if this is very simple.

I have adjusted my color and font in the editor window to display exactly how I prefer it to look.  What I would like to do is save these settings, then switch to different themes, and reload my color and font settings for the editor window.

I already tried exporting nothing except the color and font settings.  When I changed the theme, and tried to reload them, everything reverted back to the previous setup.

So, how do I go about doing this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is IMHO not possible, the changing the theme will reset your color settings. 
But you can create your own theme by using [Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe):

> Allows users to customize the Visual Studio 2013 color palette.  This
>   extension is supported for Visual Studio 2013 Professional and higher.

Comment: Bummer.  Oh well, at least I know now!  Thanks for the reply.